# No option for printing to PDF within Wine in NixOS

Tags: pdf, printing, wine, nixos

Most forum posts for other distros recommend installing a "cups-pdf" package to enable printing to PDF in non-standard applications like Wine. I can't find any such [package](https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=22.05&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=cups%20pdf) or [option](https://search.nixos.org/options?channel=22.05&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=cups%20pdf) in NixOS; is there one?